# Why error is giving for using Vuetify Datatable?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs2, vuetify.js

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "props" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

`v-slot`, `activator` is not working in my Vue.js code. But I don't know why. I am coping the code from their documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables I am using Vue 2.5.17 version.

Comment: You are using a prop variable maybe without declaring. For appropriate solution kindly add your code over here.

Comment: My code is full copied from given link. I did't change anything.

Comment: Can u add the codepen link of your code or add the code snippet here?Bcoz without code how can someone debug your problem?

Comment: https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: look at the code from vuetify 2.00beta it has some improvements may help.

Comment: you linked an empty codepen

Comment: did you install vuetify? and that error usually comes when you have not declared the props correctly, at least that is what i saw in my vue code(i am fairly new to vue as well)

Answer (score 0):

`v-slot` is not supported until Vue v2.6 as seen here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html

So two options:

- You could either go back to the  `slot` + `slot-scope` approach with a Vue version less than 2.6.0.
- Or you can upgrade your Vue version to v2.6.0.